# Rename files based on directory names

Tags: shell-script, files, rename, jpeg

How can I rename .jpg files in multiple folders based on the name of the folder? I also want the `.jpg` files to remain in their respective folders and not moved. The folder names have no spaces.

So, for example, if the folder name is Red, then I want the resulting file names to be:

```
Red000001.jpg
Red000002.jpg
Red000003.jpg
```

I have the following command, but it gives undesirable results, moving renamed files outside of their respective folders and making the file names "sloppy":

```
start=$PWD;
for directory in *; do
  cd "$directory";
  for filename in *; do
    mv "$filename" ../"Folder $directory - $filename";
  done;
  cd "$start";
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to `cd` in and out of several directories then it makes sense to use `cd -` instead which takes you to the last current working directory. Or you use `pushd` / `popd` (in `bash`).

```
for directory in *; do
  pushd "$directory"
  index=1
  for filename in *; do
    extension="${filename##*.}"
    if [ "$filename" != "$extension" ]; then
      extension=".$extension"
    else
      # i.e. there is no dot in the file name
      extension=""
    fi
    target_filename="${directory}$(printf "%06d" "$index")${extension}"
    if [ -f "$target_filename" ]; then
      echo "File ${target_filename} exists; aborting."
      exit 3
    fi
    mv "$filename" "${target_filename}"
    ((index++))
  done
  popd
done
```

This code does not handle name collisions (if there is already a file `Red00004`) well. It just checks and aborts.

Comment: Tx, that works well! Can you modify it so that the jpg extension is retained in the renamed files?

Comment: @user8547 Now the code detects the file extension and adds it. I.e. it works with mixed extensions, too.