# Copy only files with certain extension while renaming each file according to the parent folder

Tags: linux, rename, cp

I have several directories:

```
├── folder1.x
│   ├── dsferwe
│   ├── ewrwr342
│   ├── analysis
│   ├── fdsds
│   ├── vcxvcxz
│   ├── 324322
│   ├── export.asc
│   ├── f_random_subfolder.xf
│   │   ├── -.method
│   │   ├── desktop.ini
│   │   ├── lock.file
│   │   └── submethods.xml
│   └── Sync
├── random_folder4.x
│   ├── dsferwe
│   ├── ewrwr342
│   ├── analysis
│   ├── fdsds
│   ├── vcxvcxz
│   ├── 324322
│   ├── export.asc
│   ├── 22random_subfolder.xf
│   │   ├── -.method
│   │   ├── desktop.ini
│   │   ├── lock.file
│   │   └── submethods.xml
│   └── Sync
├── X93430.x
│   ├── dsferwe
│   ├── ewrwr342
│   ├── analysis
│   ├── fdsds
│   ├── vcxvcxz
│   ├── 324322
│   ├── export.asc
│   ├── random_subfolder222.xf
│   │   ├── -.method
│   │   ├── desktop.ini
│   │   ├── lock.file
│   │   └── submethods.xml
│   └── Sync
```

Each directory contains an `export.asc` file.

I want to `copy` all `export.asc` files to a new directory while renaming to have the same name as their parent directory. Therefore, in the end according to the example above I will have these files in a new folder:

```
folder1.x.asc
random_folder4.x.asc
X93430.x.asc
```

How can I achieve this?

**RELATED** topics I have already followed but haven't had any success

- [Rename files based on directory names](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181073/rename-files-based-on-directory-names)
- [how to rename files while copying?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115813/how-to-rename-files-while-copying)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `find -exec sh -c ...`

```
find . -name export.asc \
-exec sh -c 'cp "$1" /path/to/new/folder/"$(basename "$(dirname "$1")")".asc' sh {} \;
```

- `"$(basename "$(dirname "$1")")"` will be the name of the folder the file resides in.

Add `-i` to `cp` if you want to make sure that no files are overwritten without prior interaction.